# Convert zeros and ones to bool while preserving pd.NA in a multi column index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a multi column index dataframe. Some column headers might have `pd.NA` values.

The actual values in the dataframe might be zero, one, or `pd.NA`.

How can I transform all zeros and ones into `bool` while preserving the `pd.NA` values?

```
import pandas as pd

idx_l1 = ("a", "b")
idx_l2 = (pd.NA, pd.NA)
idx_l3 = ("c", "c")

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [1, pd.NA, 0, pd.NA, 0, 1, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        [pd.NA, 0, 1, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, pd.NA, pd.NA, 0],
    ],
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([idx_l1, idx_l2, idx_l3]),
)
df = df.rename_axis(["level1", "level2", "level3"], axis=1)

print(df)

level1     a                    b                  
level2   NaN                  NaN                  
level3     c     c  c     c     c     c     c     c
0          1  <NA>  0  <NA>     0     1  <NA>  <NA>
1       <NA>     0  1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     0     0
2          0     1  1     1     0  <NA>  <NA>     0
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something - does `df = df.astype('boolean')` not work?

Comment: OMG, I was working with ``df = df.astype(bool)``, which doesn't work. This solution seems to be the most pythonic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.replace` method:

```py
df = df.replace({1: True, 0: False})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
level1      a                          b                    
level2    NaN                        NaN                    
level3      c      c      c     c      c     c      c      c
0        True   <NA>  False  <NA>  False  True   <NA>   <NA>
1        <NA>  False   True  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  False  False
2       False   True   True  True  False  <NA>   <NA>  False
```

Comment: You're returning the original dataframe. However, I guess your solution is working fine.

Comment: @Andi good call, thanks.

Comment: @ScottC thanks. Copied the wrong things after testing this in an interactive console